# Is it possible to disable horizontal scrolling alone in listview?

Tags: vb.net, listview, scroll

Basically, I'm just wondering whether it's possible to disable horizontal scrolling while leaving vertical scrolling enabled with a listview in VB.NET without having to make a new class for it.

Why? Well, purely aesthetic, my listview currently has a tiny bit of horizontal scroll in it, which doesn't make it worth the effort to make a new class just for that, although if it can be coded without too much effort, I'd be more than willing to do that.

PS: I'm working in Windows Forms

Comment: No, it is not simple and overriding WndProc is required.

Comment: Switch to WPF or Silverlight for gaining complete control over your UI.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, and I would @DonA, but I simply feel more comfortable using normal winforms instead of WPF, I don't know why, I just do, I've had to create some WPF projects in the past, but to me it seems like an entirely different environment

Comment: I get it's a learning curve from Winforms, but the end results, for me, are worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I often use ListView controls in Details view with a single column in order to provide a list with drag-and-drop functionality, which is lacking in the ListBox control. ListView works beautifully for this apart from its annoying habit of wanting to scroll horizontally. It's possible to get around this to a degree by setting the column width to a suitable value (typically 4 less than the ListView's width) but this won't render well if the look-and-feel changes and will fail completely if the control decides to add a vertical scrollbar at run-time.

The workaround I use (and I'll admit it doesn't cope with every situation) is this. First, configure a ListView with a single column (the name is arbitrary) and hide its header:

```
lvList.View = View.Details
lvList.FullRowSelect = True
lvList.Columns.Add("ColName")
lvList.Columns(0).Width = lvList.ClientSize.Width
lvList.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None
```

Then handle the ListView's ClientSizeChanged event and use it to set the width of the column to the width of the client area (which is essentially the area the list body has to fill):

```
Private Sub lvList_ClientSizeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles lvList.ClientSizeChanged
    If lvList.Columns.Count > 0 Then
        lvList.Columns(0).Width = lvList.ClientSize.Width
    End If
End Sub
```

As the list contents change and the vertical scrollbar is added or removed, the ClientSizeChange event is fired and adjusts the width of the column so that it exactly fills the client area.